# read sharepoint filed (I'm a rookie)

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, powershell-2.0

```
. "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\\sharepoint.ps1"
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://nycs00058260/sites/usitp"
$splist = $spWeb.Lists["/Lists/OsEM1"]
$splist.GetItems("Item") | ForEach-Object{
 Write-Host $_["Item"]
}
```

I try to exact the value from a filed "Item", but is said "you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression >>>$splist.GetItems"

Can some one help me to find the reason and fix that?

Answer (score 0):

`$splist` is null because when you set `$splist = $spWeb.Lists["/Lists/OsEM1"]` it could not find the list "/Lists/OsEM1".  I do not believe that you need the "/Lists/" part.  Try it again as:

```
$splist = $spWeb.Lists["OsEM1"]
```

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME!!! and if I wanna find the ones which have "title" but no "Item" values, how can I write? this is only for display all the items after all

Comment: You should just be able to do "$splist.GetItems("Title") | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_["Title"] }" unless I misunderstood your question.

Comment: ya it works, and how to change the value into a new one, I wanna change the $_[Item]'s value